# GUI won't close when supposed to (AutoIT)

Tags: user-interface, autoit

I'm learning AutoIT and am trying to write a script for a GUI that let's
the user enter a few values, hit an OK button, and then see the same values
displayed again before hitting another OK button, quitting the script.

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
    Local $file, $btn, $msg
    Local $width1, $width2, $iOldOpt
    local $startangle, $endangle, $nomeas, $time

    GUICreate("My GUI",370,160) ; will create a dialog box that when displayed is centered
    $iOldOpt = Opt("GUICoordMode", 2)
    $width1 = 300
    $width2 = 50
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Startvinkel i förhållande till referensriktningen (grader):", 10, 30, $width1)
    $startangle = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 0, -1, $width2)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Slutvinkel i förhållande till referensriktningen (grader):", -($width1+$width2), 0, $width1)
    $endangle = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 0, -1, $width2)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Antal mätriktningar:", -($width1+$width2), 0, $width1)
    $nomeas = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 0, -1, $width2)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Mättid i varje riktning (sekunder):", -($width1+$width2), 0, $width1)
    $time = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 0, -1, $width2)

    $iOldOpt = Opt("GUICoordMode", 1)
    $btn = GUICtrlCreateButton("Ok", 155, 130, 60, 20)



    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

    $msg = 0

    ; Loop until the user exits.
    While $msg <> $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        $msg = GUIGetMsg()
        Select
            Case $msg = $btn
                ExitLoop
        EndSelect
    WEnd

    GUICreate("My GUI",370,160) ; will create a dialog box that when displayed is centered
    $iOldOpt = Opt("GUICoordMode", 2)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Startvinkel i förhållande till referensriktningen (grader):", 10, 30, $width1)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel(GUICtrlRead($startangle), 0, -1, $width2)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Slutvinkel i förhållande till referensriktningen (grader):", -($width1+$width2), 0, $width1)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel(GUICtrlRead($endangle), 0, -1, $width2)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Antal mätriktningar:", -($width1+$width2), 0, $width1)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel(GUICtrlRead($nomeas), 0, -1, $width2)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Mättid i varje riktning (sekunder):", -($width1+$width2), 0, $width1)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel(GUICtrlRead($time), 0, -1, $width2)
    $iOldOpt = Opt("GUICoordMode", 1)
    $btn = GUICtrlCreateButton("Ok", 155, 130, 60, 20)


    While $msg <> $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        $msg = GUIGetMsg()
        Select
            Case $msg = $btn
                ExitLoop
        EndSelect
    WEnd

    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Finished", GUICtrlRead($nomeas))
EndFunc
```

The script starts, displays the first GUI and let's me enter my values, but when I click the OK button nothing happens. Why is this?

This script is to some extent based on a coding exemple where clicking the OK button led you to a 'message box', as is seen in the second half of the script. What I've done is essentialy removing the MsgBox()-line and replcing it with GUICreate(). Nothing else has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
    Local $file, $btn, $msg
    Local $width1, $width2, $iOldOpt
    Local $startangle, $endangle, $nomeas, $time

    GUICreate("My GUI", 570, 260) ; will create a dialog box that when displayed is centered
    $iOldOpt = Opt("GUICoordMode", 2)
    $width1 = 300
    $width2 = 50
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Startvinkel i förhållande till referensriktningen (grader):", 10, 30, $width1)
    $startangle = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 0, -1, $width2)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Slutvinkel i förhållande till referensriktningen (grader):", -($width1 + $width2), 0, $width1)
    $endangle = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 0, -1, $width2)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Antal mätriktningar:", -($width1 + $width2), 0, $width1)
    $nomeas = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 0, -1, $width2)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Mättid i varje riktning (sekunder):", -($width1 + $width2), 0, $width1)
    $time = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 0, -1, $width2)

    $iOldOpt = Opt("GUICoordMode", 1)
    $btn = GUICtrlCreateButton("Ok", 155, 130, 60, 20)

    $1 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Startvinkel i förhållande till referensriktningen (grader):", 10, 160, 500, 20)
    $2 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Slutvinkel i förhållande till referensriktningen (grader):", 10, 180, 500, 20)
    $3 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Antal mätriktningar:", 10, 200, 500, 20)
    $4 = GUICtrlCreateLabel("Mättid i varje riktning (sekunder):", 10, 220, 500, 20)

    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

    $msg = 0

    ; Loop until the user exits.
    While $msg <> $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        $msg = GUIGetMsg()
        Select
            Case $msg = $btn
;~              MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Finished", 'Antal mätriktningar: ' & GUICtrlRead($nomeas))

                GUICtrlSetData($1, GUICtrlRead($1) & ', ' & GUICtrlRead($nomeas))
                GUICtrlSetData($2, GUICtrlRead($2) & ', ' & GUICtrlRead($endangle))
                GUICtrlSetData($3, GUICtrlRead($3) & ', ' & GUICtrlRead($time))
                GUICtrlSetData($4, GUICtrlRead($4) & ', ' & GUICtrlRead($startangle))

                GUICtrlSetData($nomeas, '')
                GUICtrlSetData($endangle, '')
                GUICtrlSetData($time, '')
                GUICtrlSetData($startangle, '')

        EndSelect
    WEnd
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```

Comment: Something like this, except that the lower half of the window would be a new window as I had imagined it.
It intended it to work like this:
1. Ask for values
2. Get OK-button
3. Show values, ask "Are you sure?"
4. Get OK-button
5. Proceed to do other things.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this

```
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

Example()

Func Example()
    Local $file, $btn, $msg
    Local $width1, $width2, $iOldOpt
    Local $startangle, $endangle, $nomeas, $time

    GUICreate("My GUI", 370, 160) ; will create a dialog box that when displayed is centered
    $iOldOpt = Opt("GUICoordMode", 2)
    $width1 = 300
    $width2 = 50
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Startvinkel i förhållande till referensriktningen (grader):", 10, 30, $width1)
    $startangle = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 0, -1, $width2)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Slutvinkel i förhållande till referensriktningen (grader):", -($width1 + $width2), 0, $width1)
    $endangle = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 0, -1, $width2)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Antal mätriktningar:", -($width1 + $width2), 0, $width1)
    $nomeas = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 0, -1, $width2)
    GUICtrlCreateLabel("Mättid i varje riktning (sekunder):", -($width1 + $width2), 0, $width1)
    $time = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 0, -1, $width2)

    $iOldOpt = Opt("GUICoordMode", 1)
    $btn = GUICtrlCreateButton("Ok", 155, 130, 60, 20)

    GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

    $msg = 0

    ; Loop until the user exits.
    While $msg <> $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        $msg = GUIGetMsg()
        Select
            Case $msg = $btn
                MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Finished", 'Antal mätriktningar: ' & GUICtrlRead($nomeas))
                GUICtrlSetData($nomeas, '')
                GUICtrlSetData($endangle, '')
                GUICtrlSetData($time, '')
                GUICtrlSetData($startangle, '')
        EndSelect
    WEnd
EndFunc   ;==>Example
```

Comment: What I wanted was a window that showed the labels, "Startvinkel...", etc. and the values you have chosen for them. I don't know if it's better to do this in the form of a GUI or a message box, but a GUI seemed to be the more approriate. I haven't worked out to what extent you can layout a message box.

Comment: How often does the user enter values? You could add some labels at the button of your GUI. Add the values there when the user hits ok.

Comment: The user will only enter values once every time the program is run. 
Are you suggesting I should put in some hidden labels that becomes visible with the entered values when I hit Ok? How Would I do that?